# Storing and Retrieving Values in Arraylist in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, arraylist

I am trying to store values in an Arraylist on button click event and trying to retrieve it on another button click. But somehow the Arraylist remains empty and I am getting no output. Plz Help!!

```
      ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 cl1 = new Class1();
    cl1.name = txt1.Text;
    cl1.course = txt2.Text;

    al.Add(cl1);
}

protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
    {
        Class1 cl = (Class1)al[i];
        Response.Write(cl.name);
        Response.Write(cl.course);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should cross-check your array to see if you're messing with it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should understand the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so I strongly recommend that article.

by understanding of the asp.net web life cycle then you would learn that variables in a web form are stateless so when you make a postback using your server controls(in your case a Button) it would refresh you variables so every time after the button_click your ArrayList (al) will be empty.

Solution:
to resolve this issue in ASP.NET you can use [ASP.NET ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or Session variables on your form to store information on your page however if you have a big volume of data (such as a collection with hundreds of records) it is not a good practice to store them on those variable as it causes slow performance on your application and fills up your server memory quickly.

so in your example you could either have the array list from a database or a static method or ViewState(not recommended though)

> ```
> protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
>    Class1 cl1 = new Class1();
>    cl1.name = txt1.Text;
>    cl1.course = txt2.Text;
>
>    al.Add(cl1);
>    ViewState["al"] = al; 
> }
>
> protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>    ArrayList al = ViewState["al"] as ArrayList;
>    for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
>    {
>        Class1 cl = (Class1)al[i];
>        Response.Write(cl.name);
>        Response.Write(cl.course);
>    } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Sir, you have explained everything so clearly and without frills, could you plz show me the right way to approach this problem. I would prefer an example of an arraylist from a database or a static method. Plz Help!!

Comment: you need a database table to store your array's info for example if you only have name and course fields then you just need a table in your database including those two fields and write either an ADO.NET or Linq2Sql codes to store your information into your database on btn1_Click event and select those information on btn2_Click.

Comment: That is a pretty simple and straight forward concept. I was actually getting confused that if I place a variable outside the scope of an event, it would become Global and could hold values that could be accessed anywhere but after reading Page Load Lifecycle, I am pretty sure that I was headed in a wrong direction. I need to concentrate on State Management. Kindly give me links to some simply laid out yet comprehensive articles if any on State Management.